# How can I create an object from a textfile using Pyyaml from outside of the main method

Tags: python, object, pyyaml

I am trying to create an object out of textfile using pyyaml in my python code.
I have the following Files:

The main method:

```
from make_conf import make_conf
c = make_conf().config
print(c.c)
```

The object, where I want to create the code:

```
from config import config
import yaml
class make_conf():
def __init__(self):
    filename = 'configs.txt'
    input_file = open(filename, 'r')
    input_string = input_file.read()
    self.config = yaml.load(input_string)
```

The Object I want to create:

```
class config():
def __init__(self):
    self.c = 4
```

The textfile I want read via pyyaml:

```
!!python/object:__main__.config
c: 4
```

I get the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 "/home/jakob/00 Link to Faubox/spielwiesen/python       /main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jakob/00 Link to Faubox/spielwiesen/python/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    c = make_conf().config
  File "/home/jakob/FAUbox/Faubox/spielwiesen/python/make_conf.py", line 11, in __init__
    a = yaml.load(input_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 72, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    return self.construct_document(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 41, in construct_document
data = self.construct_object(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 91, in construct_object
data = next(generator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 575, in construct_python_object
instance = self.make_python_instance(suffix, node, newobj=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 552, in make_python_instance
cls = self.find_python_name(suffix, node.start_mark)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 529, in find_python_name
% (object_name, module.__name__), mark)
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: while constructing a Python object
cannot find 'config' in the module '__main__'
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 1:
!!python/object:__main__.config


^
```

If I create the object right in the main method, it somehow works. Why? I would like to create the object outside of the main method!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

You have to write the textfile like this:

`!!python/object:config.config
c: 4`

The first config stands for the module name (the name of the file, where the config class is located), the second one is the name of the class. 
Whith this modification yaml knows which object it hast to create.